# How to copy the file path with escaped path separator?

Tags: visual-studio-code

My OS is windows. File path copied when right click the file and choose the "Copy Relative Path" item from the menu.

```
examples\53407041\index.jsx
```

I want to copy the file path with escaped path separator:

```
examples\\53407041\\index.jsx
```

How can I do it? I found a related [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/56279).

Answer (score 2):

I've been following that issue for awhile and it has been resolved with a setting (it works in the Insiders Build now and should be in v1.59):

`Explorer: Copy Relative Path Separator`

with options

[image: relative path separator setting]

`auto` is the default.  Try `/` to get the posix version.  This only works on the `Copy Relative Path` editor tab and explorer file/folder context menu commands, **not** on `Copy Path`.

This won't escape the Windows backward slash as you specifically requested but the posix forward slash separator works much more broadly across OS's.

> A new setting `explorer.copyRelativePathSeparator` allows to
> explicitly set the path separator to use when invoking the "Copy
> Relate Path" action. The available options are:

- `auto` (default): Uses operating system specific path separation character
- `/`: Use slash as path separation character
- `\\`: Use backslash as path separation character